# Java Web Start - shortcut creation not working (Unable to create shortcut)

Tags: java, java-web-start, shortcut, jnlp

does anyone know what path is used if you define in JNLP to make a desktop shortcut?
It seems it wants to place the Desktop shortcut on another user's Desktop where the current user doesn't have access to.
I get the error 'Unable to create a shortcut for xxxx' when I click Install shortcuts on the application.

Windows 7 64-bit Professional
Java RE 6 Update 23 32-bit

Thanks in advance!
Harm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java control panel on your control panel of system.
[image]

Click the view button on the control panel

[image]

You can select install shortcut from the menu where you click the left button of mouse on your target jnlp application from the list.

[image]

The contents are a little bit different depending on languages and os
but generally, each step might be similar with mine.

Now, you have a desktop shortcut in your system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. Just wanted to add details here so that anyone looking for the solutions gets an option to try out.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051890

Above bug could be causing the issue for you.

Additionally a minor tweak in the jnlp file would resolve the problem for you.

The href tag could be the culprit here

Not working

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://yourweburl.com/release/components/" href="MySoftwareLink.jnlp">
```

Working

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://yourweburl.com/release/components/" >
```

Comment: Your <desktop/> tag in the <shortcut> tag could also be one of the reasons. Please try removing that as well.